# Apache Karaf and Camel Metrics

Tags: apache-camel, prometheus, metrics, apache-karaf

I am using Apache Karaf 4.4.3 and Apache Camel. I added camel-micrometer to the project to collect metrics. How can I make these metrics available for reading by Prometheus? How can I create an EP so that prometheus can read the data

I looked through the Apache Camel documentation and couldn't find any information on this. On the internet I found only information on how to do it using Spring Boot.

Comment: You need to do this more manually in Karaf as its a dying platform. You need to setup some integration with micrometer and prometheus using java code, and then hook that into Camel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created bean PrometheusMeterRegistry and then published metrics data in EP that I created.